# Tic Tac Toe (New OOP Design)

Tags: c++11

Would someone be able to review my latest OOP design of my Tic Tac Toe / Noughts & Crosses program? I’d like to know what I’ve done well and whether I could improve the OOP Design. Many thanks in advance.

This is a follow-up to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253144/noughts-crosses-final-version/253166?noredirect=1#comment499768_253166) post.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <map>
    #include <algorithm>
    class Player {
    public:
        unsigned char m_symbol;
        const std::string m_type;
        int m_wins;
        int m_draws;
        virtual int nextMove() const = 0;
        Player(const unsigned char symbol, std::string&& type)
            :m_symbol{ symbol }, m_type{ type }, m_wins{ 0 }, m_draws{ 0 }{}
    };
    class Human : public Player {
    public:
        Human(unsigned char symbol) :Player{ symbol, "Human" } {}
        virtual int nextMove() const override {
            int move;
            std::cout << "Enter a number on the board (e.g. 1): ";
            std::cin >> move;
            return move;
        }
    };
    class Robot : public Player {
    public:
        Robot(unsigned char symbol) :Player{ symbol, "Robot" } {}
        virtual int nextMove() const override {       
            int randNum = 0;
            std::srand(std::time(0));   
            randNum = rand() % 9 + 1;
            return randNum;
        }
    };
    class Game
    {
        Player* one;
        Player* two;
        Player* turn;
        Player* winner;
        std::map<int, unsigned char>board;

    bool isMoveValid(const int move) {
        return std::find_if(board.begin(), board.end(), [&](auto pair) {
            return pair.first == move && pair.second == '-';
            }) != board.end();
    }
    void performMove(const int move)
    {          
        board.at(move) = turn->m_symbol;
    }
    
    void playerMove() 
    {    
        int move = 0;
        
        if (turn->m_type == "Human") 
        {
            do
            {
                move = turn->nextMove();
                if (isMoveValid(move) == false) 
                {
                    std::cout << "Invalid move!\n";
                }
            }
            while (isMoveValid(move) == false);
        }
        else 
        {
            std::vector<int>numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            do
            {
                move = turn->nextMove();
                if (isMoveValid(move) == false) 
                {
                    std::remove_if(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [&](auto &number) {
                        return number == move;
                    });
                }
            }
            while (isMoveValid(move) == false);
        }
        performMove(move);
    }
    void switchPlayers() 
    {
        turn = turn == one ? two : one;
    }
    bool win() {
        if (board.at(1) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(2) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(3) == turn->m_symbol) {
            winner = turn;         
            return true;
        }
        else if (board.at(4) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(5) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(6) == turn->m_symbol) {
            winner = turn;    
            return true;
        }
        else if (board.at(7) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(8) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(9) == turn->m_symbol) {
            winner = turn;
            return true;
        }
        else if (board.at(1) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(4) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(7) == turn->m_symbol) {
            winner = turn;           
            return true;
        }
        else if (board.at(2) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(5) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(8) == turn->m_symbol) {
            winner = turn;             
            return true;
        }
        else if (board.at(3) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(6) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(9) == turn->m_symbol) {
            winner = turn;        
            return true;
        }
        else if (board.at(1) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(5) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(9) == turn->m_symbol) {
            winner = turn;    
            return true;
        }
        else if (board.at(7) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(5) == turn->m_symbol && board.at(3) == turn->m_symbol) {
            winner = turn;       
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    bool draw() {
        return std::all_of(board.begin(), board.end(), [&](auto& pair) {return pair.second != '-'; });
    }
    void ResetBoard() {
        std::for_each(board.begin(), board.end(), [&](auto& pair) {
            pair.second = '-';
            });
    }
public:

    Game(Player& one, Player& two)
        :one(&one), two(&two), turn(&one),winner(nullptr)
    {
        board = 
        { std::make_pair(1,'-'),std::make_pair(2,'-'),std::make_pair(3,'-'),
          std::make_pair(4,'-'),std::make_pair(5,'-'),std::make_pair(6,'-'),
          std::make_pair(7,'-'),std::make_pair(8,'-'),std::make_pair(9,'-') 
        };
    
    }
    
    void DisplayBoard()
    {

        for (auto const& cell : board)
        {
            if (cell.first % 3 == 1) {
                std::cout << "\n\n";
            }
            if (cell.second != '-') {
                std::cout << cell.second << "        ";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << cell.first << "        ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }
    Player* gameLoop() {

        for (;;) 
        {
            DisplayBoard();
            playerMove();      
            if (win()) 
            {
                std::cout << winner->m_symbol << " is the winner!\n";
                break;
            }
            else if (draw()) 
            {
                winner = nullptr;
                break;
            }
            switchPlayers();
        }

        DisplayBoard();
        ResetBoard();
        return winner;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Robot robot1('X');
    Robot robot2('O');

    Game game(robot1, robot2);
    //game.gameLoop();
    std::vector<Robot>player = { robot1, robot2 };
    int round = 3;
    int roundCount = 0;
    Player* winner = nullptr;
    do
    {

        int gameCount = 1;
        int totalGamesinRound = 3;
        std::cout << "START GAME!\n";
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        std::cout << "\nROUND " << ++roundCount << ". . .\n";
        do
        {
            std::cout << "Game " << gameCount << " of round " << roundCount << "\n";
            winner = game.gameLoop();

            if (winner != nullptr)
            {
                std::cout << "Winner of game " << gameCount << " is type: " << winner->m_type << ": " << winner->m_symbol << "\n";
                winner->m_wins++;
            }
            else
            {
                system("cls");
                std::cout << "Game " << gameCount << " is a draw!\n";
                
            }

            gameCount++;
            totalGamesinRound--;
        } while (totalGamesinRound != 0);

        /* std::cout << "Game 2: Human vs Robot\n";
         game.play(robot1, robot1);*/
        std::cout << "Wins for " << robot1.m_type << ": Player : " << robot1.m_symbol << " - " << robot1.m_wins << "\n";
        std::cout << "Wins for " << robot2.m_type << ": Player : " << robot2.m_symbol << " - " << robot2.m_wins << "\n";
        std::cout << "Drawed: " << robot1.m_draws << "\n";

        auto playerWithMostWins = std::max_element(player.begin(), player.end(),
            [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs)
            {
                return lhs.m_wins < rhs.m_wins;
            });

        std::cout << "Winner of round " << roundCount << " is " << playerWithMostWins->m_symbol << "\n";
        round--;
    } 
    while (round != 0);
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question.

Comment: Apologises! I have fixed this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Overview

I enjoyed reading this, much more than the previous question. If I had to suddenly maintain this, I wouldn't have many complaints. In this review, I will comment less about the structure since I see no issues. I'll focus on the smaller things.

---

## Newlines for legibility

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
class Player {
// ...
};
class Human : public Player{
// ... 
};
class Robot : public Player {
//... 
};
class Game {
// ...
};
```

Adding new lines between the classes and the include directives IMO improves a lot. Right now to me, it looks cramped for no reason. Simply hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> more can prevent this XD.

---

## Input validation

```cpp
            int move;
            std::cout << "Enter a number on the board (e.g. 1): ";
            std::cin >> move;
            return move;
```

There is a small problem here. If you want to make your program perfect, you will have to perform a kind of *validation*. With the line `std::cin >> move`, you say that the user is going to input an **integer**. If `std::cin` receives anything else, it **fails**. Your program needs to be there to catch that fail otherwise the result is strange.

```cpp
Enter a number on the board (e.g. 1): Walter White
Enter a number on the board (e.g. 1): Invalid move!
Enter a number on the board (e.g. 1): Invalid move!
Enter a number on the board (e.g. 1): Invalid move!
Enter a number on the board (e.g. 1): Invalid move!
Enter a number on the board (e.g. 1): Invalid move!
Enter a number on the board (e.g. 1): Invalid move!
Enter a number on the board (e.g. 1): Invalid move!
// countless
```

<sup>If you want to understand why this happens, [this](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/5-10-stdcin-extraction-and-dealing-with-invalid-text-input/) article will help.</sup>

The solution is to perform an input validation, and see if `std::cin` has failed.

```cpp
    virtual int nextMove() const override {
        int move;
        std::cout << "Enter a number on the board (e.g. 1): ";
        std::cin >> move;
        if (std::cin.fail()) 
        {
            std::cin.clear();  
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
            move = -1;
        }
        return move;
    }
```

Notice I have also initialized `move` to `-1`. Now when I `return move;`, the other layer of input validation will catch the `-1` and show the user `Invalid move!` and call the function again.

```cpp
Enter a number on the board (e.g. 1): Walter White
Invalid move!
Enter a number on the board (e.g. 1):
```

---

## `playerWithMostWins` should be a member

```cpp
auto playerWithMostWins = std::max_element(player.begin(), player.end(),
            [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs)
            {
                return lhs.m_wins < rhs.m_wins;
            });
```

If instead this was a member function of `Game`, you just do

```cpp
Player* playerWithMostWins = game.playerWithMostWins();
```

And the implementation doesn't have to be complicated

```cpp
// inside your Game class

Player* playerWithMostWins() {
    return one->m_wins > two->m_wins ?  one : two;
}
```

You'll simplify the code greatly

---

( i couldn't think of a title for this )

I don't see of `std::vector` in your `main()`. The rounds don't have to be so complicated. You don't even need  a `vector`. All you need is an extra member function as I said in my previous point. That way to find the winner you just have to call it.

I also reformatted the `do-while` loops into `for` loops. Not necessary but I prefer it the new way

```cpp
    Robot robot1('X');
    Human robot2('O');

    Game game(robot1, robot2);
    //game.gameLoop();
    const int roundNB = 2;
    const int gamesNB = 2;

    // two rounds with two games each
    for(int i = 0;i < roundNB;i++)
    {

        std::cout << "START GAME!\n";
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        std::cout << "\nROUND " << i << ". . .\n";
        for(int j = 0;j < gamesNB;j++)
        {
            std::cout << "Game " << j << " of round " << i << "\n";
            Player* winner = game.gameLoop();

            if (winner != nullptr)
            {
                std::cout << "Winner of game " << j << " is type: " << winner->m_type << ": " << winner->m_symbol << "\n";
                winner->m_wins++;
            }
            else
            {
                system("cls");
                std::cout << "Game " << j << " is a draw!\n";
            }
        } 


        std::cout << "Wins for " << robot1.m_type << ": Player : " << robot1.m_symbol << " - " << robot1.m_wins << "\n";
        std::cout << "Wins for " << robot2.m_type << ": Player : " << robot2.m_symbol << " - " << robot2.m_wins << "\n";
        std::cout << "Drawed: " << robot1.m_draws << "\n";

        auto mostWins = game.playerWithMostWins();
        std::cout << "Player with the most wins: " << mostWins->m_type << '\n';
    }
```

Comment: Wow! A fantastic review as always Aryan! Thanks so much for spending your valuable time reviewing my program. This has honestly been an education for me! I may have questions! I will implement all suggestions and thank you your kind words regarding the “maintainability” of the program. Means a lot! I may or may not have questions when I go round to implement your suggestions! Thanks again!

Comment: I recommend against in-band error signalling like `-1` as a special return value indicating validation failure. Consider returning `bool` and accepting an `unsigned &` instead.

Comment: @Reinderien Why not? I don't actually see why that would be bad, because returning bool means now you need to add a lot more code (comparatively)

Answer (score 2):

Nice improvement, I see that you neglected some of the advice you were given in your previous post.

### CODE REVIEW ON CLASS DESIGN

1. `Game` class? Is it needed, highly controversial. A `Game` class expresses a general idea/concept. I would expect a Game class to be abstract. Can you make an object of a `Game`? What is a `Game`?. If the class was renamed `TicTacToe` or `CrossAndNaught`, that would be great, we know what that is, it is concrete enough to create an object. Note a Game class should be abstract because it represents a general idea, we can derived so many other games such as `BoardGame`, `RacingGame` and more, we can also derive `TicTacToe` from `BoardGame`.
2. A close look at `Game`, we see it is acting clever, most of its functionalities aren't really its, they should be part of a class called `Board`. A `Board` should be able to hold the players state, what is happening on the board, checks if a position is free and many more. I would represent a `Board` internal board representation as a 2D array, but it's up to individual's preference, it can be represented anyhow the designer feels like, though I have no idea why you used `std::map`.

3.`main` is just too cluttered to reason about, move those statements into functions, USE FUNCTIONS!!!, they make code really easy to browse through and they have little or no overhead in terms of memory or performance.

4. Now to class `Player`, why do you pass a `type`. This breaks the idea of polymorphism, we already know it is a `Robot`, but you still hold `m_type` as a data member. Worst still, you perform a check whilst performing a move, though it is unlikely, what if you derive more classes from `Player`, code size would increase, this reflect a poor design. Make use the polymorphic behavior you created.

### NITPICKS

1. You either chose to ignore platform independent clear function or forgot to implement it. `system('cls')` and `system('pause')` does not work on my `unix` platform.
2. I want to play against a `Robot`, but doing so requires me to mess with a lot of code, I might break something because `main` is so cluttered. Once again, make use of the polymorphic behavior you created.
3. Why make `m_type` a const and also make it public? I find it hard to reason about your choice, if you want to prevent modification, you have the `private` keyword.
4. 

```
Player(const unsigned char symbol, std::string&& type)
```

Lets look at this for a while, `Player` can be constructed from a `const unsigned char` and a `std::string rvalue reference`, the problem is this, the const is unnecessary, what this mean is, you take a fresh copy of symbol and make it const, a fresh copy does not affect the original symbol and making it const to avoid changes is not necessary. Make it a const reference instead, you avoid the copy and you prevent modification of the original object. Secondly, an rvalue reference reduces the ways in which `Player` can be constructed.

Player can be constructed like this

```
Player('X', "Human")
```

But not like this

```
std::string human = "Human"
Player('X' human)
```

The behavior you need is a `const std::string& type`.

5. Declaration of `one` and `two` in `Game` constructor shadows data member `Game::one` and `Game::two`. This poses no problem because of the implicit `this` qualifier, but it results to confusion of which `one` we mean. Avoid using the same names for class data members and local variables.
6. Make use of `random` header, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040940/why-is-the-new-random-library-better-than-stdrand) why `random` is preferable to `rand`. As a side note, the robot move is very slow because it might randomly select moves that are invalid multiple times. You can eliminate this by creating a `std::vector` of integers, at each move, shuffle the vector and select an element and eliminate it from the vector. This makes `isMoveValid` irrelevant.

[EDIT] If you have an std::vector of integers in `Player` for example

```
std::vector<int> validLoc {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

You can make it a static data member which means all derived object can modify and have access to it.You can shuffle the `validLoc` and grab the first element in the vector and eliminate it from the vector for a `Robot`, one nice thing about this approach, it leads to less code and you can shuffle it just once and select the first element always and delete it from the vector improving the speed a little. For a `Human`, do not shuffle the vector, take an input from the user from 1 - 9 and delete the element from the vector. Note, at each point in time, only valid locations are in the `vector`

7. Placing a move at a location does not need `at()`. We are sure the move is within the range and the extra check is unnecessary.
8. You forgot the virtual destructor for `Player` and its subtypes

Comment: Thanks so much for spending your valuable time to review my TicTacToe program. You’ve mentioned very interesting points such as calling it “game” which is more of an idea as opposed to being something concrete. I really agree with you I should be utilising the polymorphic features. But the real problem I had was the fact the robot int nextMove() and the human int nextMove() have different implementations. With the Robot move I couldn’t check that they were making a valid move from the Robot class before returning the integer. Any solutions to this?

Comment: I would edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much! Greatly appreciate your help and expertise.

Comment: Check out the edit.

Comment: Thanks so much! I shall make the changes now. You've given me lots to do which will only help with my progress in learning C++ and OOP design. Many thanks!

Comment: Just a question, would you recommend me initialising the vector of ints in the constructor of the player?

Comment: The vector<int> is a genius solution! I did not think of this!

Comment: I made a slight mistake, a virtual base would not solve the problem rather a static data member would, pardon my error. Define the vector in the implementation file.

Comment: Your point about the game class is valid. But right now the project itself is tic-tac-toe. So having a `Game` as a name for a class is absolutely fine. Sure if you are going to end up adding multiple games to this project then you need to re-consider but right now its not an issue.

Comment: Actually, `string_view` is better here, compared to `string const&`

Comment: Why do you need a virtual destructor here?

Comment: Yeah `string_view` is much better. A virtual destructor like virtual method functions guarantees that the approriate destructor is called during object cleanup.

Comment: @theProgrammer I get it, but there isn't any requirement for a cleanup here, so what's the point